# Collection view layout is nil, I've tried everything

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I set up a very custom collection view and setup everything properly I keep getting this error 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'. here is my code. I have researched my code indepthly and made sure i had no problems on my side but the solution on stack overflow did not help me resolve this  problem. It would be appreciated if someone could help me out.

```
class ProducttableViewController: UICollectionViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var createdat = [Date]()

    var datasource : [PFObject] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var locManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.delegate = self
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
        let layout = BouncyLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 111, height: 111)
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        self.collectionView?.register(ProductCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PoductCollectionViewIdentifier")
        locManager.delegate = self
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locManager.distanceFilter = 50
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        setup()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    func setup() {
        //query
        let query = PFQuery(className: "hello")
        query.order(byDescending: "createdAt")
         query.includeKey("User")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.datasource = objects!
                for object in objects!{
                    self.createdat.append(object["createdAt"] as! Date)
                }
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

    private func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            break
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .restricted:
            // restricted by e.g. parental controls. User can't enable Location Services
            break
        case .denied:
            // user denied your app access to Location Services, but can grant access from Settings.app
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.datasource.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.0, initialSpringVelocity: 3.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: ({

        }), completion: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 206)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PoductCollectionViewIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ProductCollectionViewCell

        cell.object = self.datasource[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Take notice that you assign `datasource` and `delegate` for the tableview before initializing it.

Comment: your suggestion didnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Ended up setting layout on `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Try, hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are initializing the collection view with a frame of zero. Thus the collectionViewLayout would not be added and I think that makes it nil.

Try changing: 
`self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)`

to:

`self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)` (or something that is not zero)

Answer (score 0):

If you already subclassing an `UICollectionViewController`, you dont need to re-init the collectionView, because it already has. You just need to set the layout manually

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Answer (score 0):

You collection view init should call/override

```
super.init(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout)
```

with your custom layout.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller